# breakpoints not hit native c/c++ in telegram android project

Tags: android, c++, telegram

When I start to debug telegram newest version in android studio, breakpoints hit in java code but when it comes to debug native C/C++ libs, they don't hit.

I tried running application on emulator and real device xiaomi redmi note 8 pro.

I even tried to remove -o3 optimizations in cmakelists.txt files but it didn't work neither.

I didn't have problems with debugging native codes in other projects with my current IDE
**UPDATE:**
I even set the debugger type to dual mode

Comment: Have you enabled debug information?

Comment: https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram.git this Is the code I cloned and working on I changed nothing from code and by default it was enabled